# Creating an url within a div button using django url + div button value ie div id

Tags: django, url, button

I have created a clickable div to act as  a 'button'that links to another page within my site. Is it possible to append the div ID into the url I call such that different divs call the same django url (as the base) but through the appended div id ended up going to different pages .

for example: 
this example works with the pack.id being appended but in the scenario I want to implement I do not used a django model

```
<div id="ticket1">
<a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' pack.id %}">
</div>
```

trying to do:

```
<div id="ticket1">
<a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' div.id %}">
</div>
```

what doesn't work and creates errors:

```
<div id="ticket1">
<a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' ticket1 %}">
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="ticket1">
<a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' "ticket1" %}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a variable inside your template with the `with` template tag:

```
{% with div_id="ticket1" %}     
    <div id={{div_id}}>
    <a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' div_id %}">
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

Alternatively, if each `div` represents a ticket, then you can do something like the following:

```
<div id="ticket{{ ticket.id }}">
<a  href="{% url 'student-packages-add' ticket.id %}">
</div>
```

supposing that `ticket` in `ticket.id` is an object representing an instance of your model.